# Eloquent: Can I "fake update" a model or update and then revert?

Tags: eloquent

I need to check what will the model state be after the update in order to execute a code. The problem is that the future state is hard to determine before the update and after the update it is so easy.

So I need one of the 2 things - either to:
1) Fake update a model (get the updated model, but not still written in DB)
2) Really update the model and if I don't like the result to revert this update

Is either of those things possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about the 2 option. If you are using MySQL as data layer welcome to the magic world of database transactions. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html). Laravel`s DB class provides special methods to implement transactional approach (http://laravel.com/docs/database#database-transactions). In your case it could written this way:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

$someInstance->update($data);

if ($someCondition) {
    DB::commit();
} else {
    DB::rollback();
}
```

Anyway check the docs, you might find it interesting and worth to now.
Note that MySQL table should use transaction-safe storage engine (like InnoDB), as far as I know MyISAM engine does not support transactions.